# Changing image name to a different image name (added after deploying on server) doesn't work in eclipse ee development

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am making a dynamic web page in eclipse ee environment using tomcat. When I change the image name to a different image (this different image was added afterwards), then the changes are not reflected on the webpage. I think I have already uploaded the image file on the tomcat server and I dont know how to change the image resources again. But if i make syntax changes they are reflected on the webpage. Please help.

Comment: added after deploying on server means the new image that i want on my web page was added after i had already run the website once on the tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the application properties on the **Tomcat** running.
You need to **stop** the Server(Tomcat) and make the changes in Application whatever you need...finally you can run the server again that changes will update in the web page.